# fstab entry for swap file

Tags: fstab, swap, uuid

Here is the free -m output

```
[prem@myserver: /home/prem]$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            991         218          85         267         687         360
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I have added swap space to my CentOS 7 machine by creating a swap file using following commands

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=2048
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Now the swap space has increased to 2GB

```
[prem@tuatahi: /home/prem]$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            991         284          69         265         638         292
Swap:          2047           5        2042
```

But I guess in order to make these changes permanent, I need to add fstab entry for my swap space. Here are the contents of fstab

```
UUID=ef6ba050-6cdc-416a-9380-c14304d0d206 /                 xfs     defaults        0 0
```

I am not sure how to add the swap space in terms of UUID.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks allow to check the UUID

Answer (score 15):

There is no UUID for a file.  Simply enter it as:

```
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
```

Since it's directly on the root filesystem, there's no worry about the mounting order.

Comment: @Prem If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

...and to append that line to fstab in one-shot as a non-root user:

```
$ echo '/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

The `sudo` and `tee` on the right side of the pipe (`|`) works around the somewhat surprising behavior of the redirect (`>>`) not preserving `sudo`.[1]

```
$ sudo echo '/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
-bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied
```

`tee` bifurcates the output, with one version going to stdout and the other to the file.  The `-a` flag appends rather than replaces similar to `>>` appending and `>` replacing.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider if your answer should rather have been an edit to the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299352/377345). Also, readers may wonder why you used the pipe+`tee` construct instead of executing `echo ' ... ' >> /etc/fstab` as `root` user or via `sudo`; perhaps you could add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive feedback!  I've expanded my answer accordingly.